# Fatal error in MPI_Scatter: Invalid communicator

Tags: fortran, mpi, fortran90

I am trying to parallelise a DO loop with matrix addition using MPI Scatter and I am getting the following error. I have initialised all MPI variables, done

```
  call MPI_INIT( ierr )
  call MPI_COMM_RANK( MPI_COMM_WORLD, myid, ierr )
  call MPI_COMM_SIZE( MPI_COMM_WORLD, numprocs, ierr )
```

at the start of the program and MPI_Finalise(ierr) at the end. But still I am getting the error where I am trying to do MPI Scatter

```
Fatal error in MPI_Scatter: Invalid communicator, error stack:
MPI_Scatter(766): MPI_Scatter(sbuf=0x6ab2a0, scount=0, INVALID DATATYPE,         
rbuf=0x7fff39a99398, rcount=0, INVALID DATATYPE, root=0, comm=0x43380000) failed
MPI_Scatter(641): Invalid communicator
```

I am using the default communicator MPI_COMM_WORLD everywhere in the code. I am trying to parallelise a matrix update operation by sending parts of the matrix to multiple processes. The input matrix is x and output matrix is y. X is a matrix of REAL*8 datatype with N rows and N columns. Also

```
nx = N/numberofprocesses
```

My MPI_Scatter code is as below

```
if (processid.eq.0) then
 call MPI_Scatter(x, nx, MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION,MPI_IN_PLACE, nx, MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, ierr) 
else 
call MPI_Scatter(x, nx, MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION, x, nx, MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, ierr) 
end if
```

and my gather code is

```
if (processid.eq.0) then
   call MPI_Gather(MPI_IN_PLACE, nx, MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION, y, nx, MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, ierr)
else
   call MPI_Gather(y, nx, MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION, y, nx, MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, ierr)
end if
```

What is the reason for the error?

Comment: Could you show us the corresponding code including the `MPI_Scatter`?

Comment: Maybe the `INVALID DATATYPE` is a clue... Did you check the datatypes of `sendtype` and `recvtype`? Also `scount=0` and `rcount=0` seem strange - but it's hard to tell without the actual code...

Comment: if (myid.eq.0) then
   call MPI_Scatter(x, nx, MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION,MPI_IN_PLACE, nx, MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, ierr)
  else
   call MPI_Scatter(x, nx, MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION, x, nx, MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, ierr)
  end if

Comment: yes. I also think that is the issue. what i am trying to send via MPI Scatter is a matrix. So not sure how I can achieve this. What datatype can I mention if the send type is a chunk of a matrix?

Comment: So, how does x look like and what is nx? You have to keep in mind, that nx is the number of double precisions sent to each process here. Are you sure, your nx is not actually 0, or of the wrong datatype/kind?

Comment: x is a matrix of size N,N....and nx = N/numberofprocesses

Comment: You are probably overwriting something. Could you please show more of your code?

Comment: I'm not familiar with your error message but as *haraldkl* and *Alexander Vogt* pointed out: Are you sure, that `nx/=0`? Please remember that `N/numberofprocesses==0` if `N<numberofprocesses` and both variables are `INTEGERS` or a value less than 1 is casted to `INTEGER`.

Comment: I am giving the value of N as 100 and number of processes as 4